# parsing dates in java

Tags: java, date

I have a date stored in my database as a string 14/08/2010. I want to parse it into a date in order to compare it with the current date. This is what I did but it doesn't compile I don't know why:

```
try{
      date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy").parse(rs.getString(2));
      System.out.println(rs.getString(2));
}catch(ParseException s){
      s.printStackTrace();
}
```

It prints this error:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "14/08/2010"
```

I tried changing the date format to dd/MM/yyyy but I have the same problem.

Comment: Why are you storing the date as a string to start with? And the code *does* compile - it doesn't work at *execution* time. It's important to differentiate between compile-time errors and exceptions.

Comment: In SimpleDateFormat pattern for month is 'M'.
Description==>  Month: **bold**If the number of pattern letters is 3 or more, the month is interpreted as text; otherwise, it is interpreted as a number.**bold**
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html
Use 'MM' instead of 'MMM'

Answer (score 3):

You should use `dd/MM/yyyy` as per the Date string `14/08/2010`

`MMM` matches Month name such as `Jan` , `Feb`

Read more about [SimpleDateFormat Patterns](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

---

I tried

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy").parse("14/08/2010");
```

that results into

```
Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "14/08/2010"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: when I use dd/MM/yyyy it prints this error:
java.sql.SQLException: No data found

Comment: As per `14/08/2010` date string.

Comment: Test `Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse("14/08/2010");`

Comment: SQLException? java.sql.Date != java.util.Date

Comment: Yest this works:
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse("14/08/2010"); @user3218114 thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

You don't know if the problem is with your date parser or the SQL `ResultSet`.

A debugger will tell you quickly where the problem lies.

I strongly agree with those people who argue that you should not save a DATE in a CHAR column.

I'd write it this way to give myself a chance.

```
private static final DateFormat DEFAULT_DATE_FORMAT;

static {
    DEFAULT_DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    DEFAULT_DATE_FORMAT.setLenient(false);
}


// Your method snippet
try {
    while (rs.next()) {
        String dateAsStr = rs.getString(2);
        Date date = DEFAULT_DATE_FORMAT.parse(dateAsStr);
        System.out.println(DEFAULT_DATE_FORMAT.format(date));
    }
} catch(ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    // Don't forget to close your resources in finally block.
    close(rs);
    close(statement);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Depending on field definition and Database it is possible that you get "14/08/2010____" instead of "14/08/2010".

On Oracle for instance returns a string filled with spaces when the DB field ist defined as CHAR.

With CHAR(24) you will always get a string with the length of 24 characters.

Try trim.

Comment: As per the exception there are no spaces. Date string is enclosed inside double quotes.

Comment: Test `Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse("  14/08/2010   ");` Works fine for me.